# How to connect cd/dvd drive to virtual machine from esxi shell

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, vmware-tools

I am looking for a way to connect my cd/dvd(contians an iso) to virtualmachine which runs on esxi from esxi shell. vsphere client proivdes connect to cd/dvd option which i cannot do it because i have to run the command from esxi shell.

I tried to google it but no use.Is there any command esxi provides which connects an cd/dvd to vm? or is there anyway to copy myfiles from esxi datastore to vm?

Comment: What version of ESXi are you using? Also why not use the Viclient?

Comment: i am using Esxi 6. I want to automate that process, no user interaction

Comment: I know this can be done with powercli but I don't think it's possible in she'll. The only thing I can think is that you could edit the vmx file but not sure that would work on a powered up VM?